# WordPress - Multilingual Site - Switching between two versions of single post template

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I've built multilingual site without the translation plugin.
The site is nearly finished, but I'm stuck on one single thing right now.

I have a two types of custom posts called:

- team-member
- team-member-pl

They both have singles which are:

- single-team-member.php
- single-team-member-pl.php

And there are two pages where team members cards are displayed:

- page-our-team.php
- page-our-team-pl.php

When I'm on one of the above pages let say "page-our-team.php" I can see all the team members cards. When I click on one of them cards I can see the details about this member in English, so I have language switcher at the header and I would like to create a link that will change the template if someone change the language, so if someone click on language switcher my "single-team-member-pl.php" template will be loaded but the member displayed previously wont change.
So for example if we was on the Tom Baker's card this card will be still displayed but the template will be swapped from "single-team-member.php" to "single-team-member-pl.php"

Hope I've explained this clearly.
This is only one thing i overlooked building this site :( So, hope this is achievable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to 'swap' on click, you'll need to use JS. What you could do is to regroup all information (en and pl) on one template and display the language the user want regarding the one he chooses.
Otherwise, I think you will need to reload the page or open a new one.
Hope it makes sense.

Basically I would do is keep the while loop, and create a card member template with all info (english, pl) like this:

```
<div class='card-member'>
  <button class='card-member__button-language' type="button">Choose language</button>
  <div class='card-member__english'>
    <p>English info</p>
  </div>
  <div class='card-member__pl'>
    <p>PL info</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

By default you display english and hide pl info.
Then with JS you add an event on the button.
If someone click the button, you add display none to the english part and display block to the pl part.

The user will stay on the same page and it's gone be faster for him.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how to display the regrouped data when the button is clicked? The biggest problem I can see is that when someone click on the team member card the data is displayed just because we are within the while loop for particular page and post type, so staying on this page could do the trick. Switching the template by JS will loose the data from while loop so I'm not too sure if this could work in any way.

Comment: You'll not lose any data with this solution. The idea is to use only one template for member card containing a section in english and another one in PL. Then you only use JS to display the part the user want. Hope it is clearer but I am gone edit my answer to add some information

Comment: Great! Thanks so much, all clear now, simpler than I thought, I will give it a go today. Once again thanks so much for taking the time and helping me. This is my first bilingual website, but as always I've took the hardest route possible. All because I hate translation plugins and I love to have a full control over everything. Have a great day!

Comment: My pleasure, happy to help. Good luck with the rest of the website and you are right to keep full control ;)